# UIImageView setImage not working in a delegate method?

Tags: objective-c, opencv, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a problem calling the setImage function in the opencv delegate method `processImage`.
When I call `setImage` in `viewDidLoad`, I can see the image, but when I do the same in `processImage`, it doesn't work.

What's the problem here?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // This works !
  [processImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"resistor3.jpg"]];
}

- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)img   {

  // This does not work anymore !
  [processImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"resistor3.jpg"]]; 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you modify the UI you must do it from the main thread, chances are that the delegate method, if it's being called, is called on another thread. Try this.

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)img   {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [processImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"resistor3.jpg"]];
        // I also think you should use the dot syntax, but that's purely a style thing
        // processImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"resistor3.jpg"];
    });
}
```

EDIT: Add recommendation about using dot syntax

Comment: I think it should be "dispatch_async" instead of "dispatch_sync" to avoid main UI blockage.

Comment: This code is running on a background thread so the background thread is the one being blocked not the main thread

Comment: Yeah good, point. You can guard against that, but it's probably better to just suggest `dispatch_async`