# working on parent UI from containerview (iOS - objective-c)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates

I have a method in my main viewcontroller:

```
- (void)playMusic:(NSString*)songTitle :(NSString*)songArtist :(NSString*)songDuration :(NSString*)songUrl{

    [songPlayer pause];

    songPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:songUrl]];

    [songPlayer play];

    self.songSlider.maximumValue = 100;

    self.songSlider.value = 0;

}
```

I call it from a view inside a containerview like this (from a button click)

```
 [mainController playMusic:songTitle:songArtist :songDuration :songUrl];
```

songPlayer (it s an AVPlayer) is doing his job well, the song start without problem.
But the songSlider (it s an UISlider) is not updated.

If I call the exam same instructions:

```
self.songSlider.maximumValue = 100;

self.songSlider.value = 0;
```

inside viewDidLoad method of my main cotroller, songSlider is updated without problem.

That makes me think the problem is that I call the function from the containerview? in this case how can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Try using `[self.songSlider setValue:animated:]`

Comment: @ChrisLoonam What does animated stand for? I have this error: Use of undefined indentifier "animated"

Comment: Call it like this: `[self.songSlider setValue:0.0 animated:YES]`. If you want the slider to animate the change, put `YES`. Otherwise, put `NO`.

Comment: Also, if you are using Interface Builder, make sure that the outlet for `songSlider` is connected.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam Thank you but it's still not working. I guess it's because I'm calling the function from the child containerview but I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: @ChrisLoonam yes the outlet is well connected, as I can change the slider value and it s working when I do it from viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975341/uiimageview-setimage-not-working-in-a-delegate-method/21975410#21975410) about an hour ago.

I suspect the problem to be that your button click action is not being called on the main thread. I didn't find any resources to indicate if UIControl always fires events on the main thread and thus there is a possibility that your code is running on a background thread. This is important because you cannot make UI modifications on any other thread than the main thread.

Try the following in your button callback

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [mainController playMusic:songTitle:songArtist :songDuration :songUrl];
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what is happening yes.

And I have tried your code, it freezes the simulator. 
What should it do?
Thank you for your time

Comment: I have no idea why the simulator would freeze to be honest. You can try only wrapping the songSlider changes in a dispatch_sync call on the main thread. Another thing you might wanna checkout is `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait modes:(NSArray *)array` you'll need to use NSInvocation because you have too many arguments for the method though

Comment: Nope, even if I call dispatch_sync with nothing wrapped, it freeze the simulator.

Btw, the mthod isn t called from an other thread but from an other controller inside a container

Comment: The thing is the method is called as the response to a button press. As I said I am not sure if the button press is called on the main thread, if it is you shouldn't use the dispatch_sync call. You can verify the thread by setting a break point in the button press code and looking at the 6th tab in the Navigator called `Debug Navigator`

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure about witch thread is doing what. 
Here is a screen of the breakpoint: http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/2561/u6yo.png

Comment: It's running on the main thread, e.g you don't need the dispatch_sync call. What you can also do is put a breakpoint inside you playMusic method and verify that the slider is not `nil`

Comment: in fact the songSlider is nil, I am uploading a screenshot so you can see there is something strange hard to explain

EDIT: as you can see on the screenshot, there is no songSlider but a _songSlider object, and it is nil.

http://i.imgur.com/k8eDc1u.png

Comment: Also, and I guess this can be useful to you, this is how I call the function from the parent:
 mainController = [[TL_ViewController alloc] init];
[mainController playMusic:songTitle:songArtist :songDuration :songUrl];

So my idea is that the maincontroller is an other instance of "TL_ViewController"and that s why he cannot access the visible UI

Comment: Yes that's probably it. You must have a reference to the actual mainController instance

Comment: I fixed it using: parent = (TL_ViewController*)[self parentViewController];
    [parent playMusic:songTitle:songArtist :songDuration :songUrl];